# How to remove an XML node from a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string containing XML tags and I convert the string values into `XmlDocument`.

It has multiple tree nodes, so I want to remove the last node from the string.

```
string strvalue = Request.QueryString["Data"];    
strvalue = "<menulist><requestId>1529866354</requestId><msisdn>918885473702</msisdn><starCode>600</starCode><keyWord>600DYN</keyWord><userData>*600#</userData><featureId>DYNAMIC_USSD_MENU</featureId><url1><![CDATA[http://216.198.200.36/USSD/receive.aspx]]></url1><dataSet><param><id>CIRCLEID</id><value>1</value></param></dataSet><timeStamp>2014/01/31 11:04:26</timeStamp></menulist><msisdn>918885473702</msisdn>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(strvalue);

//Get your nodes
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//menulist");

//This will build your string
StringBuilder yourString = new StringBuilder();
yourString.Append("user details : ");

//Iterates through your String appending the available Names
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    yourString.Append(node["Name"].InnerText + ",");
}

//Variable for your final string (replaces the trailing comma with a period)
string result = yourString.Remove(yourString.Length - 1, 1).ToString() + ".";
Response.Write(result);
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your trying to do but doesn't Last( ) work?

Comment: Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034797/splitting-html-string-into-two-parts-with-htmlagilitypack

Comment: why don't u use substring to remove the last node by index, u can find index of last node by using .LastIndexOf("any string") ?